# TCP/IP programming, data in more than one packet

Tags: tcp

I am writing an application in C, using libpcap. My program listens for new packets and parses them
according to a grammar. The payload actually is XML.

Sometimes one packet is not enough for an XML file, so the XML buffer is splitted into separate packets.
I want to add code logic in order to handle these cases. However I don't know in advance that a packet does not contain the whole data. How do I know that a packet has more data that will be send next? How to i recognize that a new packet contains the rest of the data?

Do I have to use the TH_FIN flag? Could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in TCP that defines packets, that's up to the higher layers to define if they need to - TCP is just a stream.

If this is raw XML over a TCP stream, you actually need to parse the xml - you'll know when you have a whole xml document when you've received the end of the document element.
If it's XML packaged over HTTP , you might be able to parse out the Content-Length: header which should contain the length of the body.

Note, reassembling a TCP stream from captured packets is a very hard problem, there's *a lot* of corner cases, e.g. you'd need to handle retransmission , out of sequence tcp segments and many more. http://libnids.sourceforge.net/ might help you.

Answer (score 1):

As Anon say use a higher level stream library.

But even then you need to know the chunk side before starting to handle it, as you will read from the stream in block's of n bytes.

Thus you want to first send in binary the number of bytes to be sent, then send x bytes, and repeat, thus when you are receiving the chucks via `select`/`read` to know went you have all of chunk one to pass to the processor.

Comment: That'll only work if you're the terminating end, not if you're sniffing existing connections

Comment: Agreed, I missed the the sniffing/snooping element, and just assumed he was doing sockets the hard way..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TCP, use a TCP library that gives you the data as a stream instead of trying to handle the packets yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Stream is good.  Another option is to store the incoming data in a buffer (eg char*) and search for application messaging framing characters or in the case of Xml, the root end tag.  Once you've found a complete xml message at the front of the buffer, pull it out and process.

Answer (score 0):

The XMPP instant messaging protocol, used by Jabber, has means to move XML chunks over a TCP stream.  I don't know how exactly it is done myself, but [RFC 3290](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html) is the protocol definition.  You should be able to work it out from that.